# If $12\mid{a}$ then $4\nmid{b}$ or $4\mid{(8+2a+5b)}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

Prove that if $12\mid{a}$ then $4\nmid{b}$ or $4\mid{(8+2a+5b)}$.

I have gotten thus far:

Since $12\mid{a}$, then $a=12k$ for some integer $k$.
Substitute $a=12k$ into $(8+2a+5b)$ to get $8+24k+5b$.

Not sure what to do from here, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint:  if $4 \,\nmid \,b$ then you are done. So, now assume $b=4m$

Comment: @lulu Why are you answering in comments? (Hints are answers)

Comment: $\large 2\mid a\,\Rightarrow\,4\mid 2a,\,$ so $\ \large 4\mid 8\!+\!2a\!+\!5b\iff 4\mid 5b\iff 4\mid b\ \ $

Comment: But isn't it that $4\nmid{b}$?

Comment: @Arthur I find it good that not everyone posts answers that are not longer than one line in a comment just to collect some reputation points.

Comment: @Peter It's not about reputation. It's about getting an answer out there and getting the system to understand that (for instance getting this off the unanswered queue, and make this a viable target for closing other questions as duplicates). This site as a whole would've been (margnally) better off if lulu had put that hint in an answer post.

Comment: @Arthur OK, to support this, I posted an answer.

Comment: @macy $\large \ 4\nmid b\,$ or $\,\large P(b)\ $ is equivalent to $\ \large 4\mid b\,\Rightarrow\, P(b)\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Assume $12|a$ and $4|b$ , otherwise nothing has to be proven, then , we can write $a=4s$ and $b=4t$ with intgegers $s,t$

Then, we have $$8+2a+5b=8+8s+20t=4(2+2s+5t)$$ hence $4$ divides $8+2a+5b$